# 36, 6 календарных дней или календарного дня. Как правильно?

Tags: орфография

36,6 календарных дней, при округлении – 37.

Comment: Как так 36,6 округляется до 47?

Comment: Я это тоже видела, но потом решила 47 – это какое-то сакральное число в этой теме.

Comment: @Sharon  В какой теме?

Comment: @
Александр Стрелец
 В теме, откуда Максим взял эту фразу.

Comment: @Sharon Ну подскажите, что за тема-то? У меня поиск не находит...

Comment: @ Александр Стрелец  Не могу подсказать, закрытая инормация.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: ***36,6 календарного дня.***

Почему? Тридцать шесть и шесть десятых **(долей чего?)** дня.

[Материал из Интернета](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5/)

**Числительное**

**Правильными являются конструкции** 35,5 процента (не ...процентов), 12,6 километра (не ...километров), 0,68 квадратного (кв.) **метра** (не …метров),  т. е. при смешанном числе существительным **управляет дробь, а не целое число;** так же: 45,0 (сорок пять и ноль десятых) **секунды,** 67/8 (шесть и семь восьмых) **метра** и т. п.

**Список литературы**

(1) Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию/Д.Э. Розенталь, Е.В. Джанджакова, Н.П. Кабанова//38. Формы имен числительных, §166. Сочетания числительных с существительными

(2) [Ответ Грамоты.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=0,68)

**Сравнить (из ответов Грамоты.ру):**

Правильно:  **пять с половиной метров.** Целое число управляет существительным.  ***С половиной*** — словосочетание.

Но если мы используем для записи числовую форму, где есть целое число **и дробь**, правильно: 5,5 метра.